# Blueman showing random devices and ids

Tags: bluetooth, blueman

I recently installed blueman and I'm trying to connect it to my devices.

It is showing ~20+ devices which what seems to be random names following the format:

`XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX`

I am using linux mint 20.2. I have tried using the default bluetooth manager (blueberry), but it does not list any devices. I have tried installing `bluez-tools`, it also did not work.

How do I get it to show the proper amount of devices and their names?